# How to open my iOS App from Chrome via link?

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking

The question is same as title, I already set the scheme for my iOS app and also open my app from Safari when I clicked the link. When I tried to set Chrome as my default browser then clicked the link, my app didn't open automatically or asked any permission to open it. Does anyone know what should I do?

I already put my apple-app-site-association(AASA) file on my server and set the scheme.

Comment: Do you have any updates for that?

Comment: @dacoten Not yet. It still only work on Safari.

Comment: Is there already a solution for this problem???